# update multiple rows with vb.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I loaded data from MySQL via While loop and listed on a table

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:left">id</th>
                            <th style="text-align:left">name</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center">color</th>                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <% 
                  Dim f1, f2, f3    
                    Dim rowcount, k, m As Integer

                    Dim connectionstring As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBstring").ConnectionString
                    Dim connectme As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection(connectionstring)
                  Dim ODBCdataset As DataSet = New DataSet()

                  Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT * FROM table"

                  connectme.Open()
                  Dim ODBCdataadapter As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(sqlquery, connectme)
                  ODBCdataadapter.Fill(ODBCdataset, "table")
                  connectme.Close()

                  k = 0
                  m = 1

                  rowcount = ODBCdataset.Tables("table").Rows.Count


                  Do While k < rowcount
                      f1 = ODBCdataset.Tables("ttemp").Rows(k).Item(0)
                      f2 = ODBCdataset.Tables("ttemp").Rows(k).Item(1)
                    %>

                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><%Response.Write(f0)%></td>
                        <td align="center"><%Response.Write(f1)%></td>                          
                        <td><asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="color">
                                <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="red">red</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="blue">blue</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>                       </tr>
                </tbody>
                <%   
                    m = m + 1
                    k = k + 1
                Loop%></form>
```

Table (actual table will have a few hundred rows)

```
id    name     color
1     AA       (dropdown)
2     BB       (dropdown)
```

i added a dropdownlist for the user to choose which color they prefer for each id.

Now, how can i update their chosen color into MySQL all at once? i'm assuming it's going to be a loop with something like this?

```
UPDATE table SET color='" + color + "' WHERE id=  '" & id & "'"
```

if the answer is too long, i would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction.

also, if possible, can i skip a line if the user did not choose a color for that certain id?

Comment: One general comment is that you should consider parameterizing your queries so as to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: This would be easier if using a parameterised query... You could just make the `parameter = grid.Columns(dropdownlistcolumn).Value` or something along these lines

Comment: David, could you please elaborate? Thanks